# Changing an if else statement to a switch statement

Tags: java, switch-statement, do-while

I was wondering what would be the best way to convert this if statement within a do while loop to a switch statement within a do while loop.

What would be a better way to tighten up this code?

```
    do{


        currency = keyboard.nextInt();

        if (currency == 1)
        {
            sterling = euros * 0.79;
            System.out.printf("£ %.2f", sterling);
        }
        else if (currency == 2)
        {
            usDollars = euros * 1.28;
            System.out.printf("$ %.2f", usDollars);
        }
        else if (currency == 3){
            auDollars = euros * 1.44;
            System.out.printf("$ %.2f", auDollars);
        }
        else{
            System.out.printf("Invalid Option");
        }


        System.out.printf("\nWould you like to go again");
        System.out.printf("\n1. Yes\n2  No");
        repeat = keyboard.nextInt();

        if (repeat ==  2){
            System.out.printf("Exit Program");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }while(repeat == 1);
```

Comment: Why don't you go [read up on switch statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html), try it yourself, and then ask if you run into a problem? It kind of sounds like you're asking us to do it for you.

Comment: "best way to convert this if tatement within a do while loo". I hope you know the meaning of loo. do you read your question before posting it ?

Answer (score 0):

For your example, if statement and switch will do exactly the same things. No differences.
What you could change from your code would be the last if statement:

```
if (repeat ==  2){
   System.out.printf("Exit Program");
   System.exit(0);
}
```

You can write this if statement outside the do while, and like this will be checked only once.

Comment: This will break his program, not to mention that this doesn't even answer the question.

Comment: The value of repeat is being checked by do while. If value is 1 will exit and can make the check outside if it 's equals to 2. Like this he has it, the repeat value is being checked twice in do while.

Comment: I answered the question. I just gave an extra hint.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I misread the while condition. Still, this doesn't answer the question. OP asked how to switch his `if` statements to a `switch`. Please don't just do it for him though -- this question should remain unanswered IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Switch case looks something like this

```
 switch (currency) {
            case 1:  System.out.printf("£ %.2f", euros * 0.79);
                     break;
            case 2: . 
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    .
            case n: . 
                     break;
            default: System.out.printf("Invalid Option");
                     break;
            }
```

Its no different even if it is in a loop (for, while, do while)

Read more about the [Switch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) statement and try to complete the code yourself

On a side note, no need to create variables (`sterling`,`usDollars`,`auDollars`) to store the values of the expressions `euros * 0.79` unless you are using storing for later use which doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the conversion rates in an array, then use what would have been the
switch/if variable to index that array. Something like:

```
            float[] rates = {0.79f, 1.28f, 1.44f};

            answer = euros * rates[currency-1];
            System.out.printf("$ %.2f", answer);
```

Then you don't need the selection statement(s). In general, if you see a lot of structural repetition, look for the common code and try to factor it out.